# How to get JSON object out of the cosmos DB document trigger in Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, eventtrigger

In the cosmos mongo DB, i inserted a simple document as:

```
{  
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c315585e0f53d69fc3820a1"),  
    "id" : "replace_with_new_document_id",  
    "time" : 678900.43,  
    "num" : 5678  
}
```

Then I have a Azure Function set triggered by the updates of the Cosmos Mongo DB, and I ended up get a document object as shown by the pic:

[image]

My question is what's the most easy way to get the original JSON data, i.e. "id", "time", "num" into my C# struct:

```
public struct info   
{  
  public string id;  
  public double time;  
  public int num;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement in the [official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function#prerequisites):

> Azure Cosmos DB bindings are only supported for use with the SQL API.
>   For all other Azure Cosmos DB APIs, you should access the database
>   from your function by using the static client for your API, including
>   MongoDB API, Cassandra API, Gremlin API, and Table API.

,you can't use azure cosmos db trigger function with mongo api so far.

You could follow this blog to try to bind with your cosmos db mongo api db:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-integrate-azure-functions-with-mongodb

Comment: yes, according to official document, Azure cosmos DB bindings (c# sript, *.csx) only supports SQL API, but Cosmos DB (mongo DB) trigger an Azure Function is ok, as you can see in the picture, i inserted a mongoDB document and it triggers the Azure Function and the output of the document is shown as the picture, my problem is that the info (time , id, num) i need to be in a JSON object is packaged into several layers, how to extract them out from the Json Object as shown in the picture.

Comment: @DaleWang As I know, not support does not mean error occurs,maybe it can't parse out right format.I suggest you taking a shot on the azure function mongo db trigger.

Comment: yes, thanks for your advice, i will definitely try and test.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no official support for the MongoDB API change feed, if you manage to get the document in the trigger (which obviously you can do) then simply map the `$t`-`$v` key value pair to an object and then get the value.

I would start by creating a `CosmosMongoValue` class which de-serialises the key-value pair for each property.

```
public class CosmosMongoValue<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("$v")]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator T(CosmosMongoValue<T> item)
    {
        return item?.Value;
    }
}
```

and then your Info class would looks something like this:

```
public class Info
{  
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public CosmosMongoValue<string> Id;  

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public CosmosMongoValue<double> Time;

    [JsonProperty("num")]   
    public CosmosMongoValue<int> Num;  
}
```

Then simply use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CosmosMongoValue<Info>>` to parse your string document to an object.

You can either do `.Value` to get the value of the pair or just use the value type to get the value automatically from the implicit operator I added in the `CosmosMongoValue` class.

Result:

[image]

Comment: another question is why there is this "$t" and "$v" pair when get JSON dcoument outof Azure Cosmos DB

Comment: @DaleWang Well you would never know about it if you didn't try to use a consuming method that is not supported by Microsoft. CosmosDB was built on top of the Core API which was the old DocumentDB API and new SQL API. Every API ends up being stored in the same form (a document) but with different ways to handle properties in order to the CosmosDB engine to support multiple APIs. You really shouldn't be using this because it is not supported. It's not meant to work.

Comment: understood, will try with the static client API on MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

To getting the origin ObjectId
try to decode document.id with base64

let orderId = new Buffer(document.id, 'base64').toString();
   context.log('order id: ', orderId);

in your case, the document.id is 'NWMzMTU1ODVlMGY1M2Q2OWZjMzgyMGEx'